# Error while updating database code first EF

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have a .net MVC project which works with Code first approach, I need to add a new table and the migration folder already exists and contains a lot of migrations files that have been made before; when I run `Add-Migration`:

> Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following
>   explicit migrations are pending:
>   [201304230714010_InformationalMessage, 201305231312259_Remove
>   hardcoded currencies ]. Apply the pending explicit migrations before
>   attempting to generate a new explicit migration.

So I run `Update-Database –Verbose` it gives me error:

> There is already an object named 'InformationalMessage' in the
>   database.

which seems that it goes to execute the migrations files again and it is normal to give me that error as it already exist.

Can anyone help me to how to update this code with my new table?

Answer (score 0):

Error says you are already having pending migration so first run the pending migration and then run your migration.

1. `update-database -verbose` (run first pending migration).
2. `Add-migration <nameOfMigration>` (add your migration).
3. `Update-database -verbose` (run your migration in the last).

Comment: i did already what u said and i mentioned that in my answer that it gives me  error when i run update database command "error There is already an object named 'InformationalMessage' in the database."

Comment: @AhmedAbdel-hameed Sorry I didn't noticed that. It seems you are out of sync with Nuget migration.

Comment: Nvm, what that out of sync mean or now what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

I've run into that occasionally. What I do is comment out the CreateTable command for that migration in the Up() and Down() methods. When I need a production script I am usually rolling my changes up into a single update anyways.

Comment: could you explain more in details or with example as i didn't get how can i apply your trick

Comment: If you select your migration in the \Migrations folder, it will have code to create your InformationalMessage table. You can comment this (and any other conflicts) out and the migration should run. When you need a script for production you can generate a script of all your cumulative changes http://cpratt.co/migrating-production-database-with-entity-framework-code-first/#at_pco=smlwn-1.0&at_si=54ad5c7b61c48943&at_ab=per-12&at_pos=0&at_tot=1

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily add `DropTable("InformationalMessage")` to your copy of the `201304230714010_InformationalMessage` migration – be warned, this will lose any data currently in that table, but should get you to a point where you can add your new migration … if this is a concern, make a backup of the actual table data while working on your migration.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to run "update-database" from the package manager console to push your changes to the database OR you can delete the pending migration file ([201304230714010_left]) from your Migrations folder and then re-run "add-migration" to create a brand new migration based off of your edits.